# how to add buttons above tableview in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, uitableview

i am implementing this without storyboards. currently my nib only has a tableview ( this table view is showing custom cells ) i want to add in this nib a two buttons on right and left side above the table view . such that these buttons do not get affected by scrolling and are always in view. This i am doing because once this is done then i will add checkboxes against every row and perform action using the buttons. the tableview nib is controlled using a viewcontroller file implementing tableviewdatasource and tableviewdelegateprotocol . After making these additions to nib . what changes do i have to make to the viewcontroller file h and m files.

regards
silverkid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a resized UIView (i.e. subView) and UIButtons in main UIView. Add table view in subView and required actions on buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
UIToolBar* toolBar =.... //create toolbar with yours buttons
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = toolBar;
```